# How to style PushButton's image size on hover/pressed in Qt4 using CSS

Tags: css, qt, qt4, styling

I want to have a QPushButton where the image resizes on hovering with the mouse.

The following works for QToolButton:

```
QToolButton
{
    border: 0px;
}

QToolButton:hover
{
    padding: 2px;
}

QToolButton:pressed
{
    padding: 4px;
}
```

... the image gets resized (because padding changed).

But when applying this to a QPushButton, it fails (image does not resize).

I did it the same way:

```
QPushButton
{
    border: 0px;
}

QPushButton:hover
{
    padding: 2px;
}

QPushButton:pressed
{
    padding: 4px;
}
```

When the border is increased (instead of 0) and a margin is set instead of padding you can see the resize effect applyed to the border... but the image is ignored. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, `:hover` modificator does not process dynamic changes of properties for `QPushButton`. So using of `QToolButton` is good idea. For example, text decoration (italic/underline) couldnt be changed for `QPushButton`, but could be changed for `QToolButton`. Thats why we use `QToolButton` customization instead of writing own widgets for displaying URLs.