# Underline QLabel's text "on hover"

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I want to turn the text green and underline it when the mouse cursor goes over a `QLabel`, however, it just turns green, it does not get underlined.

```
  QLabel:hover { color: green; text-decoration: underline;}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Fixed, I used:

```
void QClickableLabel::enterEvent (QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED (event);
    setStyleSheet ("QLabel { color: green; text-decoration: underline; }");
}

void QClickableLabel::leaveEvent (QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED (event);
    setStyleSheet ("QLabel { color: black; }");
}
```

Comment: You may do it with customized via QSS (to look like label) `QToolButton`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250591/how-to-style-pushbuttons-image-size-on-hover-pressed-in-qt4-using-css/18251809#18251809

Comment: You need to `setMouseTracking(true);`

Answer (score 2):

According to [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) (for both Qt 4 and Qt 5), QLabel "Does not support the :hover pseudo-state". Guess it's plain luck that it even changes the color...

To emulate, you could create a QLabel subclass and promote your widget to it. Then implement `enterEvent()` and `leaveEvent()` methods, doing necessary changes to the widget, e.g.

```
void MyLabel::enterEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    QFont f = font();
    f.setUnderline(true);
    setFont(f);
}

void MyLabel::leaveEvent(QEvent* event)
{
    QFont f = font();
    f.setUnderline(false);
    setFont(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea to implement that? As far as I know there is no "mouseHoverEvent" :/

Comment: @MattiaF. there is, but you need to set mouse tracking on

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following construction:

`QLabel *text= new QLabel("Your text"); 
text->setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold; color: green; text-decoration: underline");`

I'm using this and it's works wonderfully. ;)