# QT - emit signal when hover a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I would like to emit a signal when hovering a QLabel with the mouse in QT.

Is it possible ?

If not, how can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underline QLabel's text "on hover"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946327/underline-qlabels-text-on-hover)

Comment: You can reimplement ```MouseMoveEvent```

Comment: Actually I don't want to change css when hovering. I would like to change the label with a button

Comment: @ThibautB. How ? Should I make a subclass of QLabel ?

Comment: @LucasPierrat, Yes Subclass QLabel and overload this method

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32662362/1329652) has a complete solution to your problem and doesn't involve modifying the class you're monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You can do hover handling without subclassing of QLabel. Try next code sample for it:

```
void LabelHoverHandler::attach(QLabel *label)
{
    label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover, true);
    label->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool LabelHoverHandler::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter)
    {
        emit signalMouseHover(dynamic_cast<QLabel*>(obj) );
        qDebug() << "HoverEnter";
    }

    return false;
}
```

LabelHoverHandler header file:

```
class LabelHoverHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LabelHoverHandler(QObject *parent);
    virtual ~LabelHoverHandler() {};

    void attach(QLabel *label);

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

signals:
    void signalMouseHover(QLabel*);
};
```

Simply create an instance of `LabelHoverHandler` and call method `attach()` with a needed label as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation:

```
// mylabel.h
#ifndef MYLABEL_H
#define MYLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>

class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyLabel();
    ~MyLabel();

protected:
    virtual void enterEvent(QEvent *ev);
    virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent *ev);

private:
    bool hover;

};

#endif // MYLABEL_H
```

and:

```
// mylabel.cpp
#include "mylabel.h"
#include <QEvent>

MyLabel::MyLabel()
{
    hover = false;
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover, true);
}

MyLabel::~MyLabel()
{    
}

void MyLabel::enterEvent(QEvent *ev)
{
    if (!hover){
        hover = true;
        setText("Send signal here");
    }
    QLabel::enterEvent(ev);
}

void MyLabel::leaveEvent(QEvent *ev)
{
    if (hover){
        hover = false;
        setText("Mouse leave area");
    }
    QLabel::leaveEvent(ev);
}
```